# Getting an error while Windows 7 loads, "winrnr.dll is not designed to run on Windows"

Tags: windows-7

Below is the screenshot of the error I get while Windows 7 loads. Any idea what it is?

> C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to try:

Open an elevated command prompt (right click on the icon for cmd.exe and choose "Run as administrator.") and run: `SFC /scannow`

If that doesn't fix the problem (do a restart after running SFC to test) open an elevated command prompt again and run: `Regsvr32 winrnr.dll`

Finally, if none of the above works try an in place upgrade. (*n.b. this instructions are for Vista and I have never performed an in place upgrade for Windows 7 but I assume it is very close to being the same*)

> In-place Upgrade
>
> 1. Start the computer by using the current Operating System.
> 2. Insert the Windows Vista DVD in the computer's DVD drive.
> 3. Use one of the following procedures, as appropriate:
>
>    - If Windows automatically detects the DVD, the Install now screen appears. Click Install now.
>    - If Windows does not automatically detect the DVD, follow these steps:
>        a. Click Start, click Run, type Drive:\setup.exe, and then click OK.
>        *Note: Drive is the drive letter of the computer's DVD drive.*
>        b. Click Install now.
> 4. When you reach the "Which type of installation do you want?"
>      screen, click Upgrade to upgrade the current operating system to
>      Windows Vista.

Source: [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/constantly-receiving-cwindowssystem32winrnrdll-bad/d54737fa-9ddd-4e8a-a1bd-54ff0a266192)